# Improve database performance for geospatial

Tags: openstreetmap, postgresql, query, performance, osmosis

I have a database with osm data imported with osmosis tool. I want to search for the nearest POIs from a **given point**. For this purpose, I perform this query:

```
select id from nodes
where geom='0101000020E6100000546C713216920DC065767176C62C4540'
```

After this I would like to search tags for the selected node in `node_tags` table but my problem is that the database has 31 million rows, and the query takes more than 30 seconds. I have this columns in node tables:

- `id`, `version`, `user_id`, `tstamp`, `changeset_id`, `geom`

I run the following sentence to ensure index in "geom" column:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_nodes_geom
ON nodes USING gist (geom );
```

But it doesn't work. Query takes more than 30 seconds.

I have the following configuration in PostgreSQL database:

- **Shared buffers**: 768 MB
- **Work_mem**: 32MB
- **maintenance_work_mem**: 256 MB
- **wal_buffers**: 2 MB
- **checkpoint_segments**: 12
- **random_page_cost**: 2.0
- **seq_page_cost**: 1.0

Any idea to improve it?

Comment: What Server is Postgres on? How much RAM? 4-16GB would ideal. Indexing http://postgis.refractions.net/documentation/manual-1.3/ch04.html#id2572601

Comment: User has cloned this post here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/13387640/398670

Comment: BTW, you should really show `explain analyze` output when asking performance questions. Paste it to http://explain.depesz.com/ and link to it in the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When creating a spatial index on a table it is important to run "vacuum analyze <table>" after that.

For finding nearest points you can use operator <-> introduced in PostGIS 2.0. It actually gives you the distance between two points.
More info can be found here: http://postgis.net/workshops/postgis-intro/knn.html

```
SELECT
  id
FROM
  nodes
ORDER BY
  nodes.geom <-> 'SRID=4326;POINT(60.220 24.930)'::geometry
LIMIT 10;
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This was very helpful for me, now I get results in 1 second aprox.!!